# set equation for binary variable in GEKKO optimization problem by m.if3

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I am trying to have a array with size 52*6 as my changing variable. Also, I would like to define x[:,0] as [0,1] binary variable. I would like to have a constraint such that for any x[i,0] =1, a = 5; otherwise a = 0. The following is part of my code, it turns into a meaningless trivial solution. I am guessing I am not using m.if3 correctly, please help me for checking, thank you so much.

```
x = m.Array(m.Var,[52,6])
x[:,0]= m.Var(integer=True,lb=0,ub=1)
x[:,1:6] = m.Var(integer=True,lb=0,ub=30)

for i in range(0,52):
    a = m.if3(-x[i,0],5,0)
    m.Equation(sum(x[i,1:6]) == a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a = m.if3(-x[i,0],5,0)` function should have a switching point that is away from the solution. The numerical solvers treat `x[i,0]=1e-8` the same as `x[i,0]=-1e-8` so it may be on one side or the other of the switch point. If you need to use `m.if3()` then set the switch point away from the one solution such as `a = m.if3(-x[i,0]+0.5,5,0)` so that the values of `-x[i,0]+0.5` are between `-0.5` and `0.5`.

A better way to formulate this problem is to use the `x[i,0]` value as the binary switch that defines `a` such as:

```py
a = [None]*n
for i in range(n):
    b = x[i,0] # renaming to b
    # simplified: a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*5)
    a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*5+(1-b)*0)
    m.Equation(sum(x[i,1:])==a[i])
```

Here is a complete version that demonstrates the switching.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# define array of integer variables (nx6)
n = 3 # for testing, change to 52 otherwise
x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,6),lb=0,ub=5,integer=True)
# change upper bound to 1 for binary variables
for xi in x[:,0]:
    xi.upper = 1
a = [None]*n
for i in range(n):
    b = x[i,0]
    a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*5+(1-b)*0)
    m.Equation(sum(x[i,1:])==a[i])
m.Equation(sum(a)==5*2)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
print('a')
print(a)
print('x')
print(x)
```

With a Solution:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.339999999618158E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 

a
[[5.0], [0.0], [5.0]]
x
[[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
 [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[1.0] [0.0] [2.0] [0.0] [1.0] [2.0]]]
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you wrote `a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*5+(1-b)*0)` and not simply `a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*5)`? I'm especially confused by the multiplication by zero. Thank you.

Comment: Both are equivalent. I use this form if the switch needs to be between two values such as `x` and `y` with `a[i] = m.Intermediate(b*y+(1-b)*x)`. The `a[i]` takes the value of `y` when the binary variable `b` is `1` and it takes the value of `x` when the binary variable `b` is `0`.